# SugarCRM Account Documents and Opportunity Documents

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, relationships, documents

Via SugarCRM i would like to have all documents listed in an opportunity show up under Documents on the related account. The idea is at the account level the user gets a "birds eye view" of all documents uploaded to all opportunities associated to that account. The user then can click on any opportunity to show only documents for that opportunity. Does anyone know how i could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only could do that by code, if you are ready to code you could use this great developer blog entry to base your customization on : http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/03/11/howto-displaying-meetings-related-to-contact-in-account%E2%80%99s-subpanels/

Answer (score 2):

Simple - Add an Account relationship in the Documents module and express it the opportunities sub panel. The Opportunity documents will be tagged with the Account and When you go to the Account, you'll have your "bird's eye view" to all the opportunities documents related to that account. You shouldn't need to code this at all, it could be done in Studio.